# Convert Slim code to ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

I have this slim code:

```
.search-wrapper
  - if content_for?(:fulltext_search)
    = yield(:fulltext_search)
  - else
    - placeholder = nil unless defined? placeholder
    = form_tag collection_path, method: :get
      .input-group style='margin-bottom: 0;'
        = text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: placeholder || t(:search, default: 'search'), class: 'form-control'
        .btn-group
          button.btn.btn-search tabindex="-1" type='submit' title=t(:search, default: 'search')
            i.fa.fa-search
```

I want to convert to erb code. I have tried for some first lines:

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <% if content_for(:fulltext_search) %>
      <%= yield(:fulltext_search) %>
  <% else %>
  <% placeholder = nil unless defined? placeholder %>
      <%= form_tag collection_path, method: :get %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The think I am struggling is. I don't know how to convert this code to erb:

```
= form_tag collection_path, method: :get
  .input-group style='margin-bottom: 0;'
```

Please tell me how to converting above code.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In SLIM, whenever you see `.class-name` you can convert that to `<div class="class-name"></div>`

Also, the indentation of `.input-group`, suggests a block (`do` and `end`) in the parent `form-tag`

In your case,

```
= form_tag collection_path, method: :get
  .input-group style='margin-bottom: 0;'
```

Converts to:

```
  <%= form_tag collection_path, method: :get do %>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:0">
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

All of the indented stuff under the `.input-group` will go inside the `<div>` tags.

This was validated using the [erb2slim](http://erb2slim.com/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the built-in erb converter. Why not use that?

Just run:

```
slimrb -e your_file.slim
```

You get everything converted to erb.